# References on Nilpotent groups of class 2

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, nilpotent-groups

I wanted to read about the nilpotent groups of class 2, nilpotent groups of class 2 with exponent p and nilpotent groups of class q. Can anyone suggest some references (E.g., books, thesis, or articles that cover these topics in detail and not just definition, example and well known properties)?

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: There are hundreds of books, articles and examples of nilpotent groups (of class $q$). Have a look yourself. Did you see [this book](https://link-springer-com.uaccess.univie.ac.at/book/10.1007/978-3-319-66213-8) for example? For finite $2$-step nilpotent groups see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.01863) and the references therein.

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich Burde. The first link you shared is not directed to any reference, it opens login page of Universität Wien. Can you please mention the name of the book?

Comment: It is "The Theory of Nilpotent Groups". You can search for nilpotent groups and books.